# Not able to echo from inside the for loop

Tags: sql, batch-file, cmd

I have the following code which tries to make a sql file with all the inserts with all the different values in variable br separated by commas.
I'm able to access all the values in br in for loop but when i try to echo the whole statement it fails.

Any help?

```
@echo off

set /p uid="USER ID = "
set /p aname="APPL NAME = "
set /p rname="ROLE NAME = "
set /p cid="COMPANY ID = "
set /p br="BR = "
echo INSERT INTO USER_AUTH_BRANCH (USER_ID,APPL_NAME,ROLE_NAME,COMPANY_ID,BR) VALUES ('%uid%','%aname%','%rname%','%cid%',%%~a); > test1.sql
for %%a in ("%br:,=" "%") do (

echo INSERT INTO USER_AUTH_BRANCH (USER_ID,APPL_NAME,ROLE_NAME,COMPANY_ID,BR) VALUES ('%uid%','%aname%','%rname%','%cid%',%%~a); > test2.sql

)
```

Comment: try `for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ("%br:,= %") do (
  echo INSERT INTO USER_AUTH_BRANCH (USER_ID,APPL_NAME,ROLE_NAME,COMPANY_ID,BR^) VALUES ('%uid%','%aname%','%rname%','%cid%','%%~a'^); > test2.sql
)` You only need to escape the closing paren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the brackets:

```
@echo off

set /p uid="USER ID = "
set /p aname="APPL NAME = "
set /p rname="ROLE NAME = "
set /p cid="COMPANY ID = "
set /p br="BR = "
echo INSERT INTO USER_AUTH_BRANCH (USER_ID,APPL_NAME,ROLE_NAME,COMPANY_ID,BR) VALUES ('%uid%','%aname%','%rname%','%cid%',%%~a); > test1.sql
for %%a in ("%br:,=" "%") do (

echo INSERT INTO USER_AUTH_BRANCH ^(USER_ID,APPL_NAME,ROLE_NAME,COMPANY_ID,BR^) VALUES ^('%uid%','%aname%','%rname%','%cid%',%%~a^); > test2.sql

)
```

Here is the problem:

```
for %%a in ("%br:,=" "%") do (

echo INSERT INTO USER_AUTH_BRANCH (USER_ID,APPL_NAME,ROLE_NAME,COMPANY_ID,BR)
```

The `)` after `...BR` is being interpreted as the closing bracket for the `DO ()` block. That's why you have to escape it to make clear that it is actually meant as a part of the string.

Comment: Actually, the echo outside the loop works fine without escaping the brackets,the issue comes when it reaches  `'%uid%'` .

Comment: @PSYDUCK I've edited my answer to make clear where the error lies.